# Microsoft Report Designer Line Through Text when value not Empty

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder, report-designer, microsoft-reporting

Has anyone used LineThrough text on `Microsoft Report Designer` within the expression value? 
Example:

```
=Switch(Fields!a.Value is Nothing, "text here".LineThrough, Not(Fields!a.Value is Nothing), CStr(Fields!a.Value))
```

I need the "text here" to be strikethrough if `a.Value` is `nothing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an expression to show the value you want and then Harry's answer to set the LineThrough.

You can simplify your `SWITCH` statement for the value like this..

```
=SWITCH(
    Fields!a.Value Is Nothing, "Text Here",
    True, Fields!a.Value)
```

or if the expression will not get any more complex than you have then use `IIF`

```
=IIF(Fields!a.Value Is Nothing, "Text Here", Fields!a.Value)
```

If you need only part of the textbox then the easiest way is to use placeholders. These act almost the same way as a textbox but you can have several placeholders in a single cell/textbox each with it's own properties.

To add a placeholder click the cell/textbox first to get focus then right-click before or after any existing text/placeholders. Select `Insert placeholder` and set the expression as you wish, you can also format the placeholders font/color/decoration etc.

As an example I've got a small dataset with country names. If the country contains the word "Island" then I show different text and change the text decoration on one of the place holders. In the design you can see there are 3 placeholders, some text then a field then some more text.

[image]

When I run this I get the following output.
[image]

I've set strike thru on the countrydesc field placeholder but you can do the same on a text placeholder. You still have to do it in two parts, and expression to set the text value and an expression in the placeholders font properties to set LineThrough

Comment: Is there a way to do it in the TextBox Expression itself? Reason why I'm asking is because I have multiple fields that are printing, but I want only one of them to be with the LineThrough, example: =Switch(Fields!a.Value is Nothing, b.Value + "Line Through to the right field:"+B.Value.LineThrough, Not(Fields!a.Value is Nothing), CStr(Fields!a.Value))

Comment: DO you mean you have a single textbox  but only want part of the text to have a line thru? I'll update my answer in case that's what you want.

Comment: This is the correct way, but I'm using Report Builder 2008. After some reading realized that linethrough was not available in PDF rendering pre 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the condition on the Font/ TextDecoration on the selected report Item. There is an option for LineThrough.

**For Example**

```
=iif(reportitems!Textbox7.Value = "Cartons","LineThrough","Default")
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it in the TextBox Expression itself? Reason why I'm asking is because I have multiple fields that are printing, but I want only one of them to be with the LineThrough, example: =Switch(Fields!a.Value is Nothing, b.Value + "Line Through to the right field:"+B.Value.LineThrough, Not(Fields!a.Value is Nothing), CStr(Fields!a.Value))